# Is there a provision for AAD authentication in Logic App's http connector?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Is there a provision for AAD authentication in Logic App's http connector?
If so, how will the authentication object look like?

Or do I have to acquire the AAD token separately and then populate the same in http connector's header section?

Answer (score 2):

Logic Apps support ActiveDirectoryOAuth authentication natively, using either client secret or certificate + password

Below are the schemas for both

```
    "simpleAction": {
      "type": "http",
      "inputs": {
        "uri": "https://www.endpoint.com/certificate",
        "method": "GET",
        "authentication": {
          "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth",
          "authority": "",
          "tenant": "",
          "audience": "",
          "clientId": "",
          "pfx": "",
          "password": ""
        }
      },
    },
    "simpleAction2": {
      "type": "http",
      "inputs": {
        "uri": "https://www.endpoint.com/secret",
        "method": "GET",
        "authentication": {
          "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth",
          "authority": "",
          "tenant": "",
          "audience": "",
          "clientId": "",
          "secret": ""
        }
      },
    }
```

This is similar to Azure Scheduler authenticatin object, which is documented here
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/scheduler-outbound-authentication/#request-body-for-activedirectoryoauth-authentication